# Using where clause for R Variable in R script to use it in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, printf, rodbc

I have two tables; viz
table1 = PID (primary key) + 20 other columns & 200 records from database1 AND
table2 = [Serial no] (primary key) + 10 other columns  & 300 records from database2.

I am trying to extract values from table2 where PID = [Serial no].

Note: PID = [SCK34ICV7, NSCK876DL, ......].

I refered "Pass string Variable in R script to use it in SQL statement"

```
t1 <- sqlquery(db1, "select * from table1")
r1 <- t1$PID
class(r1) = 'factor'
t2 <- sqlquery(db2, "select * from table2 where [Serial no] = '(",r1,")' ",sep ="")
```

I also tried other functions viz paste0(), fn$ from gsubfn and sprintf() and getting error like - 'c is not a recognized built in function name' ; 'Incorrect syntax'.

Please suggest the best way to do it.

Reg,

Mrutyunjaya

Answer (score 3):

Your query is off. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) for what the proper format should be.

```
r1 <- c("PID1","PID2","PID3")
```

---

**wrong**

```
paste("select * from table2 where [Serial no] = '(",r1,")' ",sep ="")
```

output:

```
[1] "select * from table2 where [Serial no] = '(PID1)' " "select * from table2 where [Serial no] = '(PID2)' " "select * from table2 where [Serial no] = '(PID3)' "
```

---

**correct**

```
paste("select * from table2 where [Serial no] IN (",paste(r1,collapse=", "),") ",sep ="")
```

Output:

```
[1] "select * from table2 where [Serial no] IN (PID1, PID2, PID3) "
```

So the query becomes:

```
t2 <- sqlquery(db2,paste0("select * from table2 where [Serial no] IN (",paste(r1,collapse=", "),") ",sep =""))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Florian, Getting error - 42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name  'PID1'. What does this mean.

Comment: You should not use my values for r1, I created some dummy data with the line `r1 <- c("PID1","PID2","PID3")` for my example. You should use your own statement for that.

Comment: I used my own vector 'r1'. r1 <- t1$PID

Comment: Nope.  FYI, str(r1) : Factor w/ 300 levels "SCK34ICV7",..: 334 11465 21762 14917 20282 20927 15958 3514 7430 7207 ...

Comment: Well, there has to be the word 'PID1' somewhere in your code? Try CTRL+F and type in PID1.

Comment: I think it's input error. Please note - getting error for all the PIDs.     
 42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'PID1'."
 [137] "42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'PID2'."
 [138] "42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'PID3'......................